# can't override class file in module in prestashop

Tags: overriding, prestashop

I want to override class(Product.php) file using my module. If i put it in root/override/classes/Product.php then it is working.

But I want to put it in modules/my_module/override/classes/Product.php

Then it is not working for me.

If anyone done something like this then please let me know how can I do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The location that you put the file is the correct one. Note that the file must be there before you install the module. Putting it there after it's installed will do nothing, because the files from modules/my_module/override/classes/ are copied to override/classes during the installation process.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working for me on live.I have to set the permission "777" to my override directory

Comment: @user3322750 No, you don't. First, you have to learn what those permissions mean. Would 664 be enough? Because in 99.9% of cases, if you need 777 on production, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: What happens if there is already an override present in `/override/classes`?

Comment: @ Omer Sabic An error will be generated. You will need to manually merge the two files.

Comment: It is quiet "intelligent" during `/override/classes` automatic installation because it fails (probably) only when method name collision is detected (file name collision is not a problem).

Answer (score 0):

as @PrestaShopDeveloper answer the file should copy in override/classes so note directory permision for create a file , a fast but not recommended way is set directory permision of project to 777 and install your module